# Alternatives to child parent div pairing

Tags: html, css, position, parent

Ok so the goal is to be able to resize the image while the navbar and image stay paired. Have tried pairing the divs with no success.

My code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #CBB899;
}

#banana {
  position: relative;
  height: 115%;
  width: 101.65%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #CBB899;
  height: 5%;
  width: 103.65%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -53.5%;
  /*margin-bottom: 52.8%;*/
  margin-left: -3%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="banana">
  <img src="first%20page.png" alt="First Page" style="width:101.65%;height:115%;margin-left:-1%; margin-top: -1%;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href=#sixth><img src="Screen%20Shot%202018-10-20%20at%2012.03.04%20AM.png" alt="Location" style="height: 90%; width: 8%; z-index: 100; margin-left: 2%;"></a>
    <a href=#><img src="Screen%20Shot%202018-10-20%20at%2012.02.19%20AM.png" alt="Home" style="height: 90%; width: 6.5%;"></a>
    <a href=# footer><img src="Screen%20Shot%202018-10-20%20at%2012.02.41%20AM%20(2).png" alt="Contact Us" style="height: 90%; width: 9%;"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have more code but only included what was relevant.

This is what I would like the image to look like no matter the resizing ( I want the bar to of course change shape and adapt but keep inside the window), https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQht.jpg

This is what ends up happening (The behaviour of the image is spot on, shrinking to fit the window, just the navbar doesnt match)... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5nGO.jpg

Really desperate for any help, 
Thanks all 
Murdoc

Comment: You included the same image two times.

Comment: @Gerard my apologies it is fixed now